# Meta Question without one of the "must include" Tags

Tags: support, meta, required-tags

I noticed [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53441/what-is-facebook-cooking-up) (now only seen by 10k users) does not have one of the "required" tags.

I tried doing the same with a test question and got the expected errors (both as a normal question and as community wiki).

Is it just that the [original author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130154/jonathan-sampson) was a moderator at the time, so no rules apply?

**EDIT:** *Seeing as this is the answer, I'm promoting my parenthetical question:*

- Was he at least warned he wasn't following the rules?

Comment: he is now...

Comment: @quack :-) But my question is do moderators get warned they have created a question without a required tag?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Mark. @quack fixed my mistake.

Comment: [Here's another one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2606/349538)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that diamond moderators may have the power to ignore the required tags rule.  10k users can [see my test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53463/tag-test-ignore-please).  (Someone else will have to step up and test whether normal 10k+ users also have this power.)

Comment: 10k users cannot - it's just moderators

Comment: @kyle: not much of a test coming from you...  :p

Comment: As super-powers go, this ranks right up there with "talks to fish."

Answer (score 10):

moderators are immune from this rule, though they should include the required tags because it prohibits others from editing (unless they add a required tag in the edit, of course).