# Possible bug with required Meta tags

Tags: bug, required-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meta Question without one of the “must include” Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53462/meta-question-without-one-of-the-must-include-tags)

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52894/new-legal-jibba-jabba-for-your-reading-pleasure) doesn't have any of the required tags for Meta.  It was asked during 2010, and is not a migrated question, so its tags aren't covered by a grandfather clause.  It *was* asked by Jeff, though.  Is this a bug, or another Jeff Atwood Special Case?

.  Congrats!) -->

Comment: @Grace, thanks; I totally failed to dupe-search on this one.

Comment: Hm, apparently authors can't auto-close their own questions despite being able to auto-delete their own questions.

Comment: There's already a [question on that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51232/the-owner-doesnt-have-to-vote-to-delete-so-why-vote-to-close). But to do a basic field, there are restrictions against when you can delete your own post, whereas there are no restrictions against voting to close.

Comment: Also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20625/question-closed-by-a-single-non-moderator-non-asker-vote-circumstances

Answer (score 1):

♦ mods are exempt from using required tags.