# How can a question be tagged without any of the required tags?

Tags: support, tags, questions, meta, required-tags

["Duplicate of...[deleted post]"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43724/duplicate-of-deleted-post) didn't contain [any of the required tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/43724/1). How is it possible, if the questions on a meta site require at least one of the required tags?

Comment: I'm hesitant to call it a "duplicate," but see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53462/meta-question-without-one-of-the-must-include-tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Jonathan Sampson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130154/jonathan-sampson) was already a moderator when he posted that question, and [moderators were exempt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53462/meta-question-without-one-of-the-must-include-tags/53465#53465) from being required to tag a question with one of the required tags. It was still recommended that they did, though, since any normal user who edited the post subsequently would have had to add one.

Perhaps because of that situation, moderators are no longer allowed to leave off required tags as [Bill the Lizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) points out.

Comment: I just tested this, and it seems that moderators are no longer exempt from using one of the required tags.  I do remember that we used to be, so this is still the correct answer.

Comment: Ah, good to know! I updated the answer to reflect past vs. present.

Comment: I have been moderator for 90 days, during the beta phase of Drupal Answers, and I remember I could not create a question without using any of the mandatory tags. Clearly, I started being a moderator 6 months ago.

Answer (score 3):

Tim has the right answer for this case, but this can also happen when a question is migrated in from another site.

EDIT:
Okay, according to balpha, this no longer happens. There are probably some old unloved migrated posts still around, though (EDIT TO EDIT: this is an example until someone ruins it by editing it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48470/how-can-i-attach-files-to-a-question-here). I feel like I run into one every two months or so.

Comment: Not true anymore; any question migrated to a Meta that has none of the required tags will automatically be tagged [meta-tag:discussion].

Comment: Ruined ;p sorry...